# Using stream to merge two list with updated values

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a more elegant way to merge two lists in a 3rd one which take values from one and take values from second if the value is updated ?

To be clearer, let's consider I have 2 lists of users:

```
List<User> users = Arrays.asList(
        User.builder()
            .id(1).surname("john").build(),
        User.builder()
            .id(2).surname("paul").build(),
        User.builder()
            .id(3).surname("george").build(),
        User.builder()
            .id(4).surname("walter").build());


List<User> updatedUsers = Arrays.asList(
        User.builder()
            .id(1).surname("john").email("myEmail@email.com").build(),
        User.builder()
            .id(2).surname("paul").email("myEmail@email.com").build());
```

I'm expecting to get a list containing all users and common users replaced by the updated values.

I used the following code to implement the expected output:

```
Map<Integer, User> usersMap = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, Function.identity()));
Map<Integer, User> updatedUsersMap = updatedUsers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, Function.identity()));


usersMap.putAll(updatedUsersMap);
List<User> output = usersMap.values().stream().toList();
```

I do have the expected result and I just wonder if there's another way to do it using stream, more efficient and elegant.
Thanks !

Comment: it's a typo :) my object was a little bit too big :) copy paste isn't a good practice ... I fix the code sample. the implementation is working ... I just wonder if it can be enhanced

Comment: If your code works but you are looking for improvements consider posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (note: I am NOT saying it is off-topic here since question may be on-topic on many sites).

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems efficient enough to me, what is elegant might be matter of subject. Developers often use `List` when `Set` is more suitable collection (do you really want to access users by index?).

If the collections were `Set`s, `User.equals()` method was based only on the `id` field, and you want to emphasize the data of `updatedUsers` override the base data, you could describe result using set operations (yes, these are not part of standard Java - I borrow them from Guava or you can use any other implementation).

```java
Set<Users> usersSet = new HashSet<>(users);
Set<Users> updatedUsersSet = new HashSet<>(updatedUsers);
Set<Users> output = Sets.union(updatedUsersSet, Sets.difference(usersSet, updatedUsersSet));
```

The problem is shifted to higher level of abstraction which I admit not everyone must like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a dummy class for testing this code. Actually i'm using this folloging code right now on List of ListItem from SharePoint graph. Maybe should I try using more sets. In my case, with listitems, id is the only value that is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one go without creating intermediate maps if you concat the stream of users and updated users and collecting the second value if you encounter a duplicate key:

```
List<User> result = new ArrayList<>(
        Stream.concat(users.stream(), updatedUsers.stream())
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, 
                                        Function.identity(),
                                        (first,second) -> second)).values());
```

Answer (score 0):

Streams are very useful in many circumstances.  But they also incur quite a bit of overhead.  Just use a little imperative programming to do the same thing.

You are creating a new user and placing it in a list. The busy work is done. Since the updated user has been created and there is no way to tell if the user is a new user or an updated user, just add it to the map normally. It will either be added as a new user or replace an existing one.

```
Map<Integer, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
 
for(User user : users) {
    userMap.put(user.getId(), user);
}
       
for(User user : updatedUsers) {
    userMap.put(user.getId(), user);
}
```

Now you can get the updated map entries by user id.

Note: You many want to institute some syntax/invariant checking when creating the User instance. For example:

- user id out of range
- email syntax error

You can always retrieve the users as a list as follows.

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>(userMap.values());
```

If for some reason, you need to verify that a user is in the map before taking action, you can see if the user's id is already there.

```
if (userMap.containsKey(userId)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe give it a tidier look by `import`ing `static`. Also, rather than iterating each collection to add to a combined `Map`, you could use the combining `Map` as a `Supplier`:

```
Map<Integer, User> updatedUsersMap = updatedUsers.stream().
    collect(toMap(
                User::getId,
                identity(),
                (k, v) ->v,
                ()-> { return usersMap; }));
```